# How to initialize a collection property in a custom WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a custom WPF control base class. This base class registers a custom property with the type "List<"some own type">".

How can I initialize the property for design time? There should always be 8 objects in the list and the user should by able to modify this objects.

I have tried to pass a default value with the PropertyMetadata object, but the collection shown in the property editor is always empty.

```
public class CustomPropertyTestBase : UserControl
{

    static CustomPropertyTestBase()
    {
        List<object> defaultValue = new List<object>(new object[8]);
        MyCustomObjectsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustomObjects",
            typeof(List<object>), typeof(CustomPropertyTestBase),
            new PropertyMetadata(defaultValue));
    }

    public static DependencyProperty MyCustomObjectsProperty;

    [Category("MyCustomProperties")]
    public List<object> MyCustomObjects
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Whenever i add a new object in the property editor, these new objects are not stored. After reopening the property editor the list is empty again.

I have attached the debugger to the designer and the get or set methods of the property are never called by the editor.

SOLUTION:

As "dowhilefor" had mentioned. I had to change the type ObservableCollection. Now the designer stores the changed list correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: Shall the list be the same for instances of your user control (i.e. a singleton)? If not, use `new PropertyMeta(null)` instead of `new PropertyMetadata(defaultValue)` and in the public constructor, use `MyCustomObjects = new List<object>(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if( System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            MyCustomObjects = new List<object>();
            MyCustomObjects.Add("Hello");
        }
    }
```

But maybe its not the best solution. I remember there was some tools in expression blend to have dummy data, but can't remember how they did it. Of course this is static and you can't change it, but i don't think this is possible.

Comment: I have tried this and attached a debugger to the designer. The constructor is called and the List is filled correctly, but the property editor shows an empty list. The property get or set methods are never called by the editor.

Comment: that is correct, WPF doesn't use these getter and setters. Your just wrote get; set; i hope that was just to simplify and not your actual code, because that would be wrong. Also you might want to check if a ObservableCollection suits more your need, if you need active updates if you add or remove from your list.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to show sample data for design time, you should not hardcode the sample data in your C# code.

Instead, use the attribute `d:DesignData` and a supporting sample data *.xaml file to show sample data in the designer. The article [Design-time Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ee839627%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows how to do that.

Here is an additional good article about DesignData: [DesignData MVVM support in Blend, VS2010 and ...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/08/27/designdata-mvvm-support-in-blend-vs2010-and-wpf-silverlight.aspx).

Please note that DesignData works not only with Blend, but also in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

As "dowhilefor" had mentioned. I had to change the type ObservableCollection. Now the designer stores the changed list correctly. Thanks.